# How to correctly use python libraries under Windows?

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Windows 10 and I would like to import a library from some place `P:\_Testing\Tools\Selenium\Basic` (which I added to `PYTHONPATH`). I have the following script:

```
print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
from Basic import basic
```

and the path `P:\_Testing\Tools\Selenium\Basic` contains two files: a non-empty file `basic.py` and an empty file `__init__.py`. However, when running the script, I get the following output:

> Y:\BFH\Selenium\BFH_ARoeffnen.py;P:_Testing\Tools\Selenium\Basic;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4\helpers\pycharm
>
> ```
> Error
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Y:\BFH\Selenium\BFH_ARoeffnen.py", line 25, in test_b_f_h_a_roeffnen
>     from Basic import basic
> ImportError: No module named 'Basic'
> ```

So why does this not work? How to include the library in the given path correctly?

Comment: What if you add `P:\_Testing\Tools\Selenium` (i.e. the directory) that *contains* the module) to the path?

Comment: Oh well... Of course you are right... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can import basic directly, because the Basic folder is right in your PYTHONPATH.
Just like search files right in this folder, you can get result include:
basic.py
**init**.py
But can not find Basic folder itself.